# Selected tech. stack for web application - criticism / comments?

Tags: common-lisp

I'm about to build my first serious Lisp-based project: a web application that will need to scale to tens of thousands of users (not concurrently - probably hundreds, at most, concurrently).

The stack I'm intending to use looks like:

- [Weblocks](http://weblocks.viridian-project.de/) web framework with a BerkeleyDB back-end
- [Elephant](http://www.common-lisp.net/project/elephant/) object database
- [Steel Bank Common Lisp](http://www.sbcl.org/) (SBCL)
- Ubuntu Server (10.04 LTS)

I have two areas of concern re. this stack:

- Is Elephant dead?  The latest release is getting on for three years old ... which could just mean that it's stable I guess :-)
- As a relative newcomer to Lisp (but with significant RoR & ASP.NET experience) are any of those technologies likely to melt my head?

Feedback on my choices, & suggestions of alternatives, would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Elephant is effectively unmaintained. It does not work on current SBCL and the patch to fix the issue has not been applied. It's possible that someone else might pick up the development but it's not clear in the short term if that will happen. Some people use Rucksack as an object store, and bknr-datastore is also interesting.

Ubuntu is fine, but don't use Ubuntu Lisp packages; it's better to get SBCL from www.sbcl.org and libraries via Quicklisp. Because of that, almost any Linux will work equally well. I use Debian for my Lisp-powered website.

Answer (score 3):

Weblocks is a continuations-based web framework - it is a very old approach, it should not be used for developing modern web-applications.

Comment: Interesting - thanks for the feedback.  What's wrong with continuation-based frameworks, do you have a recommendation for something (CL-based) to use instead?

Comment: Some more info here: http://groups.google.com/group/weblocks/browse_thread/thread/9073746bdd6b5c7d

Comment: @archimag Please elaborate. I know nothing about Weblocks, and your answer is not very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Here's a link that was recently submitted to /r/lisp that's relevant: http://carcaddar.blogspot.com/2011/06/continuation-based-web-applications.html

Comment: @Duncan Bayne I am developing your own framework - http://restas.lisper.ru/en/ and use it together with cl-closure-template (unfortunately, the documentation is not ready yet).  For storage I use BKNR.DATASTORE or Postmodern or MongoDB (recently).

Comment: What exactly is a "modern" web-application and what are the distinguishing characteristics that separate it from a "not modern" web application?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using PostgreSQL for persistence, you should check out [Postmodern](http://marijnhaverbeke.nl/postmodern/).

Answer (score 0):

I have tried Weblocks, and i have made a simple web app also. But when i want to write a more complicated app, i found Weblocks is too limited. It lead user to write more widgets, but i suppose widgets cannot solve all web UI problem. I even read 80% source codes of Weblocks. But .... finally i decided to change another Web framework. What i really need, i suppose, is a url routing library like Ruby on Rails, *Restas* is fine. I tried it, and i wrote a blog library which support themes like WordPress using Restas. Restas is easier than Weblocks, but more powerful in my opinion.